# ¿Cómo calcular días laborables, sábados y domingos en un rango de fechas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dada dos fechas determinadas, por ej:

```
DECLARE @FechaDesde     DATETIME
DECLARE @FechaHasta     DATETIME

SELECT  @FechaDesde     = '19010113'
SELECT  @FechaHasta     = '19030521'
```

Quiero calcular cuantos días laborables, sábados y domingos hay.

Comment: La función recibe una fecha inicial, y un numero de días los cuales se les va sumar a la fecha inicial, para calcular los días festivos se ocupa una tabla configuration.diasfestivos http://www.alekztgtipsdevs.com/2017/11/funcion-sql-para-determinar-fecha-con.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

primero si este proceso es para un banco por ejemplo, tienes que crear una tabla con tus días festivos y también colocarlos por años.
en el ejemplo que agrego no tomo en cuenta los días festivos, solo los tendrías que agregar a una tabla y hacer la comparación por la fecha.

```
declare @fecha1 datetime = '20170901';
declare @fecha2 datetime = getdate();
declare @domingo int = 0
declare @sabado int = 0
declare @otrodia int = 0

while (@fecha1 < @fecha2)
begin
    if (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @fecha1) = 1)
begin
    set @domingo = @domingo + 1;
end
else if (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @fecha1) = 7)
begin
    set @sabado = @sabado + 1
end
else
begin
    set @otrodia = @otrodia + 1
end                  
    set @fecha1 = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @fecha1);
end

select @otrodia diasSemana, @sabado sabado, @domingo domingo;
```

cualquier cosa envía mensaje, saludos!!! ej para sql server.

otra cosa revisa el idioma de tu base por que el weekday suele variar con respecto al idioma!

Answer (score 3):

Hay dos formas de hacerlo, la primer es por "fuerza bruta". Básicamente generamos todos los días del rango solicitado en una tabla temporal y verificamos que día de semana es cada uno, sumando luego dónde corresponda. Algo así:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

-- Generamos las fechas (10000 dias)
DECLARE @Fechas TABLE (
    Nro         INT,
    DiaSemana   INT,
    Fecha   DATETIME    
)

INSERT INTO @Fechas(Nro)
SELECT  (T1.NRO-1)*1000 + (T2.NRO-1)*100 + (T3.NRO-1) * 10 + T4.NRO
    FROM ( SELECT 1 AS 'NRO' UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) T1 
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS 'NRO' UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) T2
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS 'NRO' UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) T3
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS 'NRO' UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) T4
    ORDER BY T1.NRO,T2.NRO,T3.NRO

UPDATE  @Fechas
    SET DiaSemana = DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, Nro-1, @FechaDesde)),
    Fecha =  DATEADD(DAY, Nro-1, @FechaDesde)

-- Consulta final
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN F.DiaSemana BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'LaV',
    SUM(CASE WHEN F.DiaSemana = 6             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sab',
    SUM(CASE WHEN F.DiaSemana = 7             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dom'
    FROM @Fechas F
    WHERE F.Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde AND @FechaHasta
```

La generación de la secuencia de fecha puede hacerse de varias maneras, yo elegí hacer un "producto cartesiano" de 10 registros hasta llegar a tener unos 10.000, que me permite generar cada fecha y establecer que día de la semana es. Por último solo hay que sumar cada caso para llegar al resultado final:

```
LaV    Sab    Dom
------ ------ ------
614,00 122,00 123,00
```

La otra alternativa es más directa y surgió de una respuesta de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563069/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-tuesdays-between-two-dates-in-tsql) pregunta. No requiere armar ninguna tabla intermedia, solo hace los calculos pertinentes

```
-- Consulta final
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN F.DiaSemana BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN F.Cant ELSE 0 END) AS 'LaV',
    SUM(CASE WHEN F.DiaSemana = 6             THEN F.Cant ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sab',
    SUM(CASE WHEN F.DiaSemana = 7             THEN F.Cant ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dom'
    FROM  (
        SELECT  1 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -7, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -6, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  2 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -6, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -5, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  3 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -5, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  4 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -3, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  5 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -3, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  6 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  7 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY,  0, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant
    ) F
```

El resultado termina siendo el mismo:

```
LaV    Sab    Dom
------ ------ ------
614,00 122,00 123,00
```

Answer (score 0):

GENTE, me parece que es mucho mas sencilla y precisa esta opcion. Testeen esto y me dicen

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
declare @FechaIni date = '20190901';
declare @FechaFin date = '20190930';
declare @dias int=0;
WHILE @FechaIni <= @FechaFin
BEGIN  
   if  datepart(dw, @FechaIni) not in (6,7) SET @dias=@dias+1
   set @FechaIni=dateadd(dd,1,@FechaIni)
END  
print @dias
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, te invito a leer [answer], si bien tu aporte es interesante te recomendaría editar la misma y agregar una explicación de como este script soluciona la duda expuesta

Comment: Es básicamente la misma solución que ya dió Dave Rincon, pero tampoco responde exactamente lo que pidió el AP, ya que no dice la cantidad de sábados y domingos

Answer (score 0):

/*Calcula los dias habiles en el mes **actual** */

```
declare @mes as tinyint
declare @fecha as smalldatetime
declare @dias_habiles as tinyint
declare @ciclo as tinyint
set @fecha=getdate()- (day(getdate()-1))
set @mes=month(@fecha)
set @dias_habiles=0
set @ciclo=@mes

while @ciclo=@mes
begin
if month(@fecha+1) = @mes 
begin
set @fecha=@fecha+1
if datepart(DW, @fecha) between 2 and 6
begin
set @dias_habiles=@dias_habiles+1
end
end
else
begin
set @ciclo=month(@fecha+1)
end
end
select @fecha, @dias_habiles
```

Answer (score 0):

En este ejemplo, la variable @start_date y @end_date representan las fechas de inicio y fin del período que se desea calcular. La función DATEDIFF() se utiliza para calcular el número total de días entre las dos fechas.

Para calcular el número de días laborables, se restan los fines de semana completos (es decir, dos días por cada semana completa en el rango) y luego se restan el primer domingo y el último sábado si es que están presentes.

Para calcular el número de sábados y domingos, se cuenta el número total de semanas entre las dos fechas y luego se restan el primer sábado o domingo y el último sábado o domingo si es que están presentes.

Finalmente, se muestran los resultados en tres columnas: "WorkingDays" para el número de días laborables, "Saturdays" para el número de sábados y "Sundays" para el número de domingos en el rango de fechas especificado.
igualmente te dejo un enlace con mas validaciones [validaciones comunes de sql](https://thedevelopmentstages.com/validar-fechas-en-sql-server/)  o [Calcular los dias laborables del calendario](https://thedevelopmentstages.com/calcular-dias-laborables-en-sql/)

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE = '2022-03-01'
DECLARE @end_date DATE = '2022-03-31'

-- Calcular el número de días laborables

DECLARE @working_days INT = 
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @start_date, @end_date) + 1) -- Número total de días
    - (DATEDIFF(wk, @start_date, @end_date) * 2) -- Restar los fines de semana completos
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @start_date) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Restar el primer domingo
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @end_date) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Restar el último sábado

-- Calcular el número de sábados y domingos
DECLARE @saturdays INT = 
    (DATEDIFF(wk, @start_date, @end_date) + 1) -- Número total de semanas
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @start_date) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Restar el primer sábado
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @end_date) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Restar el último domingo
    
DECLARE @sundays INT = 
    (DATEDIFF(wk, @start_date, @end_date) + 1) -- Número total de semanas
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @start_date) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Restar el primer domingo
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @end_date) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Restar el último sábado

-- Mostrar los resultados
SELECT @working_days AS WorkingDays, @saturdays AS Saturdays, @sundays AS Sundays
`
Para calcular el número de días laborables, sábados y domingos entre dos fechas en SQL Server, puedes utilizar una combinación de funciones y cálculos de fechas. Aquí hay un ejemplo que muestra cómo hacerlo:

less
Copy code
DECLARE @start_date DATE = '2022-03-01'
DECLARE @end_date DATE = '2022-03-31'

-- Calcular el número de días laborables
DECLARE @working_days INT = 
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @start_date, @end_date) + 1) -- Número total de días
    - (DATEDIFF(wk, @start_date, @end_date) * 2) -- Restar los fines de semana completos
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @start_date) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Restar el primer domingo
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @end_date) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Restar el último sábado

-- Calcular el número de sábados y domingos
DECLARE @saturdays INT = 
    (DATEDIFF(wk, @start_date, @end_date) + 1) -- Número total de semanas
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @start_date) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Restar el primer sábado
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @end_date) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
-- Restar el último domingo
    
DECLARE @sundays INT = 
    (DATEDIFF(wk, @start_date, @end_date) + 1) -- Número total de semanas
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @start_date) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Restar el primer domingo
    - CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @end_date) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Restar el último sábado

-- Mostrar los resultados
SELECT @working_days AS WorkingDays, @saturdays AS Saturdays, @sundays AS Sundays
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Si copias código debes hacer las atribuciones necesarias.