# Calculo de minutos y horas entre dos fechas, teniendo en cuenta días hábiles y horarios de apertura y cierre

Tags: sql

Estoy realizado un calculo para obtener los minutos y horas entre dos fechas, pero teniendo en cuenta dos condiciones:

```
1. Días hábiles (Lunes a viernes) sin festivos
2. Hora de inicio y cierre de la bodega
```

De esta manera estoy realizando el calculo, pero no están correctos los datos, me pueden ayudar.

```
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
            CASE WHEN Fecha_Inicio = MIN(Fecha) THEN Hora_Inicio ELSE [Hora Inicio Bodega] END,
            CASE WHEN Fecha_Cierre = MAX(Fecha) THEN Hora_Cierre ELSE [Hora Fin Bodega] END) AS Minutos,

        DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
            CASE WHEN Fecha_Inicio = MIN(Fecha) THEN Hora_Inicio ELSE [Hora Inicio Bodega] END,
            CASE WHEN Fecha_Cierre = MAX(Fecha) THEN Hora_Cierre ELSE [Hora Fin Bodega] END) / 60 AS Hora
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: `De esta manera estoy realizando el calculo, pero no están correctos los datos` Qué significa que no son correctos los datos? Qué problema tienen los datos? Por favor agrega un [example] par poder ayudarte

Comment: @AndresGardiol La salida que tengo no es correcta, de acuerdo al query adjunto en la pregunta. Me podrías ayudar en orientar o abordar este caso de manera diferente para poder tener un resultado correcto.

Comment: Si por supuesto. Lee el artículo de [example]. Básicamente te falta agregar un ejemplo de cómo esperas que sea el resultado. Si solo dices `pero no están correctos` por más que lo intentemos no sabemos qué es lo que necesitas hacer. Debes proveer un ejemplo. Y por favor no lo agregues en los comentarios. Has click en [edit] para editar tu pregunta. Y ya que estamos, por favor realiza el [tour]

Comment: Por el lado de la cantidad de días, ya se ha respondido, revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105572/c%c3%b3mo-calcular-d%c3%adas-laborables-s%c3%a1bados-y-domingos-en-un-rango-de-fechas

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular los minutos y horas entre dos fechas teniendo en cuenta días hábiles y horarios de apertura y cierre, necesitarás considerar varios aspectos adicionales en tu cálculo.

Aquí hay una estructura básica que puedes seguir para realizar este cálculo:

1. Identifica los días hábiles entre las fechas de inicio y cierre, excluyendo los festivos. Puedes consultar una lista de festivos o utilizar un servicio o librería que te proporcione esta información.
2. Para cada día hábil, verifica si es el primer día (Fecha_Inicio) o el último día (Fecha_Cierre), ya que estos días pueden tener horarios de apertura y cierre diferentes.
3. Calcula los minutos y horas para cada día hábil individualmente:

   - Si es el primer día, calcula los minutos desde la Hora_Inicio hasta el horario de cierre de la bodega (Hora_Cierre), teniendo en cuenta los minutos de apertura y cierre de la bodega.
   - Si es el último día, calcula los minutos desde el horario de apertura de la bodega (Hora_Inicio Bodega) hasta la Hora_Cierre, teniendo en cuenta los minutos de apertura y cierre de la bodega.
   - Si no es ni el primer ni el último día, calcula los minutos desde el horario de apertura de la bodega hasta el horario de cierre de la bodega, sin considerar los minutos de apertura y cierre.
4. Suma todos los minutos calculados para obtener el total de minutos entre las fechas.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo se podría estructurar el cálculo utilizando SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @Fecha_Inicio DATETIME;
DECLARE @Fecha_Cierre DATETIME;
DECLARE @Hora_Inicio_Bodega TIME;
DECLARE @Hora_Cierre_Bodega TIME;

-- Asigna los valores correspondientes a las variables

-- Calcula el total de minutos y horas
SELECT
    SUM(CASE
        -- Primer día
        WHEN Fecha = @Fecha_Inicio THEN
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Hora_Inicio_Bodega, @Hora_Cierre_Bodega) - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Hora_Inicio_Bodega, Hora_Inicio) + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Hora_Cierre, @Hora_Cierre_Bodega))
        -- Último día
        WHEN Fecha = @Fecha_Cierre THEN
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Hora_Inicio_Bodega, @Hora_Cierre_Bodega) - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Hora_Inicio_Bodega, Hora_Inicio_Bodega) + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Hora_Cierre_Bodega, @Hora_Cierre_Bodega))
        -- Día intermedio
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Hora_Inicio_Bodega, @Hora_Cierre_Bodega)
    END) AS Minutos,
    SUM(CASE
        -- Primer día
        WHEN Fecha = @Fecha_Inicio THEN
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Hora_Inicio_Bodega, @Hora_Cierre_Bodega) - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Hora_Inicio_Bodega, Hora_Inicio) + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Hora_Cierre, @Hora_Cierre_Bodega))
        -- Último día
        WHEN Fecha = @Fecha_Cierre THEN
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Hora_Inicio_Bodega, @Hora_Cierre_Bodega) - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Hora_Inicio_Bodega, Hora_Inicio_Bodega) + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Hora_Cierre_Bodega, @Hora_Cierre_Bodega))
        -- Día intermedio
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Hora_Inicio_Bodega, @Hora_Cierre_Bodega)
    END) / 60 AS Horas
FROM
    (SELECT
        Fecha,
        CASE WHEN Fecha = @Fecha_Inicio THEN @Hora_Inicio ELSE @Hora_Inicio_Bodega END AS Hora_Inicio,
        CASE WHEN Fecha = @Fecha_Cierre THEN @Hora_Cierre ELSE @Hora_Cierre_Bodega END AS Hora_Cierre,
        @Hora_Inicio_Bodega AS Hora_Inicio_Bodega,
        @Hora_Cierre_Bodega AS Hora_Cierre_Bodega
    FROM
        tabla_fechas
    WHERE
        Fecha >= @Fecha_Inicio AND Fecha <= @Fecha_Cierre
        AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Fecha) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
        -- Puedes agregar aquí condiciones adicionales para excluir festivos si tienes una lista o un servicio que los provea
    ) AS fechas_habiles;
```

Asegúrate de reemplazar `@Fecha_Inicio`, `@Fecha_Cierre`, `@Hora_Inicio_Bodega` y `@Hora_Cierre_Bodega` con los valores correspondientes en tu implementación.

Recuerda adaptar la consulta y las condiciones adicionales según tu esquema de base de datos y la forma en que estás almacenando y obteniendo los datos de fechas y horarios.

Comment: No uses ChatGPT para [responder preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy). El usuario vino a Stackoverflow apra que un humano lo ayude con su problema, si hubiera querido usar ChatGPT lo habría hecho por su cuenta